# Not able to connect to MS SQL DB instance with ms sql driver 13 from Linux 7(CentOS7) Env

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc, isql

I am trying to connect from Linux virtual environment to MS SQL Server instance using ms sql driver 13.

```
[<user> ~]$ which odbcinst
/usr/bin/odbcinst
[<user> ~]$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/<user>/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
[<user> ~]$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[DNSname-1]
Driver = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
SERVER=server-1
DATABASE=DB1

[DNSname-2]
Driver = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
SERVER=server-2\instance-1
Database=DB2
[<user> ~]$ isql DNSname-1 userid1 passwd1
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> quit
```

isql is able to connect to ms sql server

```
[<root> ~]$ isql -v DNSname-2 userid2 passwd2
[S1T00][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

But When I try to connect to sql db instance, isql is giving an error as "Login timeout expired"

Comment: Is that second instance set up to allow remote connections as the error message suggests ? You should be able to simply run `telnet server-2 1433` or `telnet server-2 1434` on your linux server to verify it can connect to that server.  If telnet can't connect , is the server at least reachable on the network (e.g. can you atleast ping server-2 successfully ?)

Comment: Yes I am able to connect to same server-2/instance1 from my local(Windows) system.

Comment: But that's not remote a remote connection, so that's an entirely different way of connecting to the server. Did you try the suggestions I gave you ?

Comment: Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux is unable to resolve instance names. Look [here](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) for a workaround.